# Please Help me construct ETL solution

Tags: ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I Have a package where I want to realise the constraint based on variable "Path"
**Example:** If the Path = 1, package need to use picture 2 (With Task 2_1,Task 2_2)

But the Tasks: Task 2_1, Task 2_2 doesn't executes.
If I delete the constraint marked red (picture 3), Tasks 2_1, Task 2_2 Executes.

If I run with parameter Path =0, problem is the same, task 2_1,2_2 doesn't executes.
Please help me what i doing wrong ?

Picture1   http://postimg.org/image/6cmd434mz/
   Picture2   http://postimg.org/image/yhh49k26h/
   Picture3   http://postimg.org/image/y5znwslqh/
   Picture4   http://postimg.org/image/ozhd9igi1/

Sorry That Url are links. I cannot add by images in editor, because have old version of internet explorer on my computer

Comment: Could you more clearly link your text to the Pictures? I can see references to picture 2 and picture 3 , but no mention of pictures 1 & 4? Also what sort of variable is "Path" and how is it set? Could it possibly contain a null value?

Comment: It might help to debug the variable values during a run. Note: Click on Debug > Windows > Locals, to show you the current running value of your variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set up the constraints so both 1 1 and 1 2 1 need to be completed. According to other logic in your package this will never happen. You need to change the properties of the constraints so only one of both needs to complete.

[Change the property of the constraints from `Logical AND` to `Logical OR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141722.aspx)